# Configure ForwardedRequestCustomizer in cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty

Tags: java, jetty, cxf

Can anyone provide a clue how to configure ForwardedRequestCustomizer in jetty provided by cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty 3.1.1? cxf.xml and httpj namespace  do not seem to have support for it. I need to handle X-Forwarded-Proto headers as SSL is terminated on load balancer before jetty. Version of jetty is 9.2.10. Spring 4.1.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding ForwardedRequestCustomizer in Java code after cxf.xml processing (i.e. after Endpoint.publish)

```
private void configureForwardedRequestCustomizer()
    {
        JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory factory = new JettyHTTPServerEngineFactory();
        JettyHTTPServerEngine engine = factory.retrieveJettyHTTPServerEngine(port);
        Iterator<ConnectionFactory> iter = engine.getConnector().getConnectionFactories().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext())
        {
            HttpConnectionFactory f = (HttpConnectionFactory) iter.next();
            f.getHttpConfiguration().addCustomizer(new ForwardedRequestCustomizer());
        }
    }
```

Please note that this works as cxf maintains static mapping between port number and engine.